# Can we add isolation level in spring transaction while doing create or delete?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-transactions, transaction-isolation

My question is here . In spring mvc services we are applying isolation levels based on our needs. Can we follow same while doing create/delete services in spring?

Is there any loss/gain by doing/not doing this ?